# Is "As if I lived" correct?

Tags: word-choice, as, if

> Please charge me for the book as if I **lived**  in Australia .

Is this sentence correct? Does it mean that I am not living in Australia?

Would it better  to write "as if I was living"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your sentence states that ***you are not living in Australia***. You can either say:

> Please charge me for the book as if I lived in Australia.

or

> Please charge me for the book as if ***I were living*** in Australia.

I would prefer the second because it refers to a specific point in time:  "Please charge me for the book as if ***I were living*** in Australia" *(at the moment of speech)*.

Comment: So as if i lived in Australia does not mean that i am not living  at the moment of speech

Comment: Of course it does, it includes the moment of speech. But when you use the continuous aspect, the emphasis lies on that particular moment. The fact that in your sentence somebody is asked to do something _NOW_, suggests that.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct. Yes, *it says you are not living in* Australia because of the words *"as if"* meaning *"like."*

You could use "*was living*" instead and so think of that action as not true and very unlikely to be the case.

This emphasizes the meaning of unreality.

It can also mean you are being ironic about it and if you used "*lived*," that would express something like "*I have never lived in Australia before.*"

However, saying either "*as if I am living,*" "*as if I live,*" or "*as if I've lived*" would be correct too.

Now you can see the difference and decide which one is better in your context.